# How can I loop through an object to return all values of an element?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

```
$result = $stripe->subscriptions->search([
  'query' => $myquery,
]);
echo $result;
```

So my result returns an object =

"data": [ { "id": "ID1", "metadata": [metadata1], "plan": { "id": "price_1LmLWsAxhRgWB6Y4zjxfO4dD", etc etc

"data": [ { "id": "ID2", "metadata": [metadata2], "plan": { "id": "price_1LmLWsAxhRgWB6Y4zjxfO4dD",  etce etc

If I write:

```
$metadataofdata1 = $result->data[1]->metadata;
```

I get the metadata of the first set of data.

How do I get the metadata of all instances?

```
So $metadataofdata1 = $result->data[EveryIndexHere]->metadata;
```

I think it is a forloop, but I have been told I can't forloop an object?

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Preferably I'd like to get an array of metadata so that I can return further data, based on the metadata in that array. So if metadata1 exists return "subscribedtoplan1" If metadata2 exists return "subscribedtoplan2".

Comment: If `$result->data` is an array, you can `foreach ( $result->data as $data ) { echo $data->metadata; }`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```php
foreach($result as $r){
print_r($r);
}
```